# cli can't find folder that is right there

Tags: command-line, directory-structure

I'll admit that i'm a noob at ubuntu, i only have it installed for 2 days.
i wanted to delete the stacer config folder through the terminal but it says it can't find it, even when i typed rmdir with the complete directory of the folder. what am i doing wrong?

(btw the text is in french but it basically says that it was impossible to complete the action since there was no such file)

```
gabriel@acer:~/.config/stacer$ sudo rmdir /.config/stacer
rmdir: impossible de supprimer '/.config/stacer': Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The preceding `/` is the problem.  It's looking in your root instead of in your home directory.

Try:

```
rmdir ~/.config/stacer
```

Since it's in your home directory, `sudo` is probably unnecessary.